# Getting links of a YouTube channel using API for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am making a website for my YouTube channel so I need to have links of the videos updated automatically. I dont know much about this so I am asking this question.. Please help me..

Comment: You should try taking a look at youtube API, it can be found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi first you need to know that the link is basically:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID

so you need to get from utube api only the videoID that you need not a full link. and then you can build the link alone.

check this video it will summarize it all:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcUauzCn7RE